# Смена мест ключей и значений в словаре

Tags: python

Есть словарь вида:

```
{'apple:': ['apple1,', 'apple2'],....}
```

Как мне поменять местами значения ключей и их значений?
Чтобы получился такой:

```
{'apple1:': 'apple', 'apple2:': 'apple',...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если в лоб, то так:

```
arr = {'apple:': ['apple1,', 'apple2'], 'banana': ['banana1', 'banana2', 'banana3']}

res = dict()

for obj in arr.items():
    for elem in obj[1]:
        res[elem] = obj[0]

print(res)
```

1. пройти по всем ключам,
2. пройти по всем значениям для каждого ключа
3. создать новые элементы для нового словаря

Answer (score 2):

В Питоне есть dict comprehensions. Цикл по парам ключ/значение, вложенный цикл по значению:

```
import pprint

arr = {
    'apple:': ['apple1,', 'apple2'],
    'banana': ['banana1', 'banana2', 'banana3']
}

pprint.pprint({i: k for k, v in arr.items() for i in v})
```

Результат:

```
{'apple1,': 'apple:',
 'apple2': 'apple:',
 'banana1': 'banana',
 'banana2': 'banana',
 'banana3': 'banana'}
```